# Alignment of Multiple TeeChart's Chart Control along Bottom Axis

Tags: c#, .net, teechart

[image: TeeChart's Multiple Chart Alignment along the Bottom X-Axis Issue]

Currently we are having sync issue using TeeChart's Chart Control (.net / c#). In the example shown in attached screenshot, we have two chart controls whose right vertical axis are synced perfectly. Top chart contains area chart while bottom chart contains volume chart. While drawing vertical lines on both charts at specific time interval, we found that vertical lines drawn in both charts having the same value are not synced. Please note that both charts are plotted with same dataset.

We did some r&d on the same issue and our observations states that it is due to different chart styles used in TeeChart's. But as per our client's requirement we need to sync this vertical lines across multiple charts. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The code below align the vertical line for both Series. I think you can do something like that:

```
  public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeChart();
    }

    Steema.TeeChart.Axis axis1;
    DateTime dt; 
    private void InitializeChart()
    {
        tChart1 = new Steema.TeeChart.TChart();
        tChart1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Controls.Add(tChart1);
        tChart1.Aspect.View3D = false;
        axis1 = new Steema.TeeChart.Axis();
        tChart1.Axes.Custom.Add(axis1);
        axis1.Horizontal = false;

        tChart1.Axes.Right.StartPosition = 0;
        tChart1.Axes.Right.EndPosition = 50;

        axis1.StartPosition = 51;
        axis1.EndPosition = 100;

        axis1.OtherSide = true;
        axis1.AxisPen.Visible = false;
        dt = DateTime.Now;
        tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Labels.DateTimeFormat = "dd/MM";
        tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Labels.Style = Steema.TeeChart.AxisLabelStyle.Value;
        InitializeSeries();
        tChart1.Draw();

        tChart1.AfterDraw += TChart1_AfterDraw;
    }

    private void TChart1_AfterDraw(object sender, Steema.TeeChart.Drawing.Graphics3D g)
    {
       for (int i=0; i<tChart1[0].Count; i++)
        {
            Point point1, point2;
            point1= new Point(tChart1.Axes.Bottom.CalcPosValue(tChart1[0].XValues[i]),tChart1.Axes.Right.CalcYPosValue(tChart1[0].YValues[i]));
            point2= new Point(tChart1.Axes.Bottom.CalcPosValue(tChart1[0].XValues[i]), axis1.CalcYPosValue(tChart1[0].YValues[i]));
            g.Line(point1, point2);
        }
    }

    private void InitializeSeries()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            if (i==0)
            {
                new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Area(tChart1.Chart);
                tChart1.Series[i].XValues.DateTime = true;
                (tChart1.Series[i] as Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Area).AreaLines.Visible = false;
                (tChart1.Series[i] as Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Area).Color = Color.BlueViolet;
                (tChart1.Series[i] as Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Area).Transparency = 20;
                Random rnd = new Random();
                for (int j=0; j<10; ++j)
                {
                    tChart1.Series[i].Add(dt, rnd.Next(100));
                    dt = dt.AddDays(1);
                }

                tChart1.Series[i].Marks.Visible = false;
                tChart1.Series[i].VertAxis = Steema.TeeChart.Styles.VerticalAxis.Right;
            }
            else if(i==1)
            {
                new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Volume(tChart1.Chart);
                tChart1.Series[i].DataSource = tChart1.Series[i - 1];
                tChart1.Series[i].CustomVertAxis = axis1;
            }
        }          
    }
```